# Simulate click of RadioButton in Google Chrome with SendMessage

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have an application that performs clicks in the Google chrome browser through `sendmessage`. It works perfectly when I click on all components of the page without problem with a single exception: I can not select a RadioButton.

This is the only part I can not click:

[image: screenshot]

I have already tried the PostMessageA And SendNotifyMessage alternatives without success, and I also found code on the internet that supposedly solved the problem, but no success - I've included that code below.

Observation: it would not be feasible using conventional click system for my application.

Alternatives that already tried

```css
SendMessage(Window, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, Direction, MakeLong(X, Y));
SendMessage(Window, WM_LBUTTONUP, Direction, MakeLong(X, Y));
```

```css
PostMessageA(Window, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MakeLParam(X, Y));
PostMessageA(Window, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MakeLParam(X, Y));
```

```css
SendNotifyMessage( Window, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, Direction, MakeLong(X, Y) );
SendNotifyMessage( Window, WM_LBUTTONUP, Direction, MakeLong(X, Y) );
```

**Code that promises to solve the problem however did not work**

```css
procedure TForm1.ChromeBugFix;
var
  texto: string;
  specialfolder, I: integer;
  ARQ: TStringList;
  Ln, NewLn: String;
  caminhochrome: String;
begin
 specialFolder := CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA;
 caminhochrome := GetSpecialFolderPath(specialFolder);
 caminhochrome := caminhochrome + '\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State';
  if fileexists(caminhochrome) then
  begin
   ARQ:=TStringList.Create;
   ARQ.LoadFromFile(caminhochrome);
   ARQ.Text:=StringReplace(ARQ.Text,'"enabled": true','"enabled": false',[rfReplaceAll]);
   ARQ.Text:=StringReplace(ARQ.Text,'"hardware_acceleration_mode_previous": true','"hardware_acceleration_mode_previous": false',[rfReplaceAll]);
    for I := 0 to ARQ.Count - 1 do
    begin
      ARQ[0] := '{ "hardware_acceleration_mode": { "enabled": false },';
    end;
     ARQ.SavetoFile(caminhochrome);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Did you examine the HTML that generated these radio buttons? What are they? JavaScript emulations of a radio button?

Comment: <input name="cdTipoArquivo" value="IMG" id="IMG" title="Arquivo Imagem" type="radio">

Comment: Faking input is probably the wrong approach

Comment: Have you read and understood what the supposed solution does? It makes some modifications to a JSON file, although it appears not to worry about JSON formatting at all. That's a bad idea, but maybe it happens to work sometimes. When you run the code, does it make the modifications correctly? If you make the modifications yourself, does it work? Remember that Chrome mustn't be running while modifying its settings.

Comment: You may have been able to save yourself a lot of time if you'd just used Selenium instead of writing your own program.

Comment: Rob Kennedy
I've tried it still fails

Comment: There is a curious fact if I write the following code in the navigation bar and to enter the ok in the mesage click works in radio buttun normally CODE: javascript:alert(":D");

Comment: We appear to be talking to ourselves here. Don't expect anyone to help if you ignore what they say.